# How to setup a base model in inference mode?

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#finetuning) about fine-tuning states that it is important to "*keep the BatchNormalization layers in inference mode by passing training=False when calling the base model.*". (What is interesting, that every non-official example that I've found about the topic ignores this setting.)

Documentation follows up with example:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.xception import Xception

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(150, 150, 3),
    include_top=False)  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.
base_model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
scale_layer = keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1 / 127.5, offset=-1)
x = scale_layer(x)

# We make sure that the base_model is running in inference mode here,
# by passing `training=False`. This is important for fine-tuning, as you will
# learn in a few paragraphs.
x = base_model(x, training=False)

x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs , outputs)
```

The thing is that the example is adding preprocessing to the base model and my model(EfficientNetB3) has already preprocessing included and I don't know how to set my base_model with `training=False`` without prepending it with additional layer:

```
base_model = EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
base_model.trainable=False
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model) # How to set base_model training=False?
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="classifier"))
```

**How to prove that `training=False` or `training=True` has an effect:**

@Frightera explained to me how to "lock" the model's state and I wanted to prove to myself that the lock happens by checking BatchNormalization non-trainable variables. My understating is that if I call model with `training=True` then it should update the variables. However, this is not the case, or am I missing something?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3
import numpy as np


class WrappedEffNet(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedEffNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet', 
                                                       include_top=False,
                                                       input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
        self.model.trainable=False
    
    def call(self, x, training=False):
        return self.model(x, training=training) # Modified to pass also True.
    

base_model_wrapped = WrappedEffNet()

random_vector = tf.random.uniform((1, 224, 224, 3))

o1 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector)

o2 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector, training = False)

# Getting all non-trainable variable values from all BatchNormalization layers.
array_a = np.array([])
for layer in base_model_wrapped.model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'moving_mean'):
        v = layer.moving_mean.numpy()
        np.concatenate([array_a, v])
        v = layer.moving_variance.numpy()
        np.concatenate([array_a, v])

o3 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector, training = True) # Changing to True, shouldn't this update BatchNormalization non-trainable variables?
array_b = np.array([])
for layer in base_model_wrapped.model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'moving_mean'):
        v = layer.moving_mean.numpy()
        np.concatenate([array_b, v])
        v = layer.moving_variance.numpy()
        np.concatenate([array_b, v])

print(np.allclose(array_a, array_b)) # Shouldn't this be False?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to invoke the `call` method of the base model in Sequential model as in Functional. However, you can think the model as if it is a custom layer:

```
class WrappedEffNet(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedEffNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet', 
                                                       include_top=False,
                                                       input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
        self.model.trainable=False
    
    def call(self, x, training):
        return self.model(x, training=False)
```

Sanity check:

```
base_model_wrapped = WrappedEffNet()

random_vector = tf.random.uniform((1, 224, 224, 3))

o1 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector)
o2 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector, training = False)
o3 = base_model_wrapped(random_vector, training = True)

np.allclose(o1, o2), np.allclose(o1, o3), np.allclose(o2, o3)
# (True, True, True)
```

It is inference mode regardless of the value of `training`.

Model summary is the same as Sequential:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 wrapped_eff_net (WrappedEff  (1, 7, 7, 1536)          10783535  
 Net)                                                            
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (G  (1, 1536)                0         
 lobalAveragePooling2D)                                          
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (1, 1536)                 0         
                                                                 
 classifier (Dense)          (1, 10)                   15370     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 10,798,905
Trainable params: 15,370
Non-trainable params: 10,783,535
_________________________________________________________________
```

Edit: In order to see difference of `BatchNormalization`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(1, 2) * 20 + 0.1

bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input((x.shape[-1], ))
output = bn(input_layer )

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer , outputs=output)
```

`model.trainable = False`:

```
model.trainable = False
for i in range(2):
    print('Input:', x)
    print('Moving mean:', model.layers[1].moving_mean.numpy())
    print('training = True -->', model(x, training = True).numpy())
    print('training = False -->', model(x, training = False).numpy())
    print()

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0. 0.]
training = True --> [[ 2.5019286 12.437845 ]]
training = False --> [[ 2.5019286 12.437845 ]]

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0. 0.]
training = True --> [[ 2.5019286 12.437845 ]]
training = False --> [[ 2.5019286 12.437845 ]]
```

`model.trainable = True`, `training = True`:

```
model.trainable = True
for i in range(2):
    print('Input:', x)
    print('Moving mean:', model.layers[1].moving_mean.numpy())
    print('training = True -->', model(x, training = True).numpy())
    print()

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0. 0.]
training = True --> [[0. 0.]]

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0.02503179 0.12444062]
training = True --> [[0. 0.]]
```

`model.trainable = True`, `training = False`:

```
model.trainable = True
for i in range(2):
    print('Input:', x)
    print('Moving mean:', model.layers[1].moving_mean.numpy())
    print('training = False -->', model(x, training = False).numpy())
    print()

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0.04981326 0.24763682]
training = False --> [[ 2.476884 12.313342]]

Input: [[ 2.50317905 12.44406219]]
Moving mean: [0.04981326 0.24763682]
training = False --> [[ 2.476884 12.313342]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. You wrote that _It is inference mode regardless of the value of training._ That statement actually should be quite the opposite. My understanding is that when you call model with `training = True` you specifically allow to update BatchNormalization's non-trainable weights. So, the result of `np.allclose` should be `(True, False, False)` and it will be, but you've made a typo in `def call(self, x, training): return self.model(x, training=False)` it should be `def call(self, x, training): return self.model(x, training=**training**)`

Comment: No, the model always will be in inference mode, I showed that `training =True` does not effect the **base model's** state. Because in the Sequential model's training phase, it will calculate the forward pass by `model(x, training = True)` which you don't want in base model. In other words, that forward pass' `training` argument will not effect the base model. You wanted that, didn't you?

Comment: Thank you I understand now what you did. Could you kindly take a look at my updated question? In your answer you have proven that non-trainable variables are not updated. However due to lack of my knowledge in the topic, I can't figure out how to prove that by checking this on an individual layer level. I am trying to analyse the variables but they are not changing.

Comment: You did not assign the concat results to the arrays so they are empty, it should have been `array_b = np.concatenate([array_b, v])` I guess? Regarding to the other question, nice catch, it will be `False` if you remove `model.trainable = False`. That's because `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` are updated during training not during inference.

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Wodzu Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Once again, thank you for this. I will check results on Wednesday when I will be back from holidays and let you know.

Comment: I did check your answer. Thanks for catching up my mistake with `concatenate` and for extended example! Exactly what I wanted.